# Compare a file for tokens and generate common tokens/values

Tags: python

I have two files-

```
file1
token1=1234
token2=1245
token3=2345
token4=345


file2
token1=2345
token2=345
token4=4935
```

I want to generate a new file, which has all the tokens from file1 that are also present in file2 and I want to keep the token, values from file 2. This is my code, but for some reason I miss random common values.

For example:

In file one, the line is:

```
IA_ITD_Worst_V = 0y100010100
```

In file2 it is:

```
IA_ITD_WORST_V = 0y100010100
```

I expect `IA_ITD_WORST_V = 0y100010100` in the output file but it doesn't appear.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

```
f1=open("file1","r")
f2=open("file2","r")
f3=open("commonfile.txt","w")

line1=f1.readline()
line2=f2.readline()

for line2 in f2:
    tokenname=line2.split('=')[0].strip()
    for line1 in f1:
        if tokenname==line1.split('=')[0].strip():
               f3.write(line2)

    f1.seek(0) #reset to first line


f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

I am sure there are more efficient ways, but this is a simple approach that should work?

Comment: "But for some reason I miss random common values." What *exactly* is wrong with your output? This is vague.

Comment: I see some common tokens in file1 and file2 that do not get written to file 3. They are exactly the same- no caps/spacing tabs etc. that are different. I do not understand why they are not being written to the output file.

Comment: Can you revise your question with a specific example?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how else to better describe it, but for the files I described in the question, example would be my program not finding token2 as a common value (and not writing it to commonfile.txt

Comment: The issue is there may be some *data-dependent* issue which we can't see without a *specific* example. If that's the case, a description is not enough. That's why I ask for a *specific* example, i.e., showing a *real* line from f1 and from f2 which is *actually* not in f3 but which should be.

Comment: Also, this isn't your actual code--this code would produce a `NameError` because `counter2` is referenced before assignment. Post your actual code, or better yet the smallest subset of your code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, removed the offending statement. Here is a line not found          IA_ITD_WORST_V = 0y100010100
The line not found--- in file 1 it is IA_ITD_Worst_V = 0y100010100
---in file2 it is IA_ITD_WORST_V = 0y100010100

Comment: I don't see anything in your comment. Please edit your question with the lines and please include *both* of them (from file1 *and* the corresponding one from file2).

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon. THanks a lot for your time.

Comment: these two tokens obviously have different capitalization--why would you expect them to match? `'Worst' != 'WORST'`. (And please edit your question with this data--it should not be buried in a comment since it is central to your issue.)

Comment: Thanks so much, I don't know I must be going blind!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
f1 = open('file1.txt', 'r')
f1_tokens = set(line1.split('=')[0].strip() for line1 in f1)

f2 = open('file2.txt', 'r')
for line2 in f2:
    if line2.split('=')[0].strip() in f1_tokens:
        print line2,
```

Usage: `python script.py >commonfile.txt`

Comment: This solution 1) includes the header line of `f1` as a token (probably not intended) and 2) has very poor runtime behavior -- `x in f1_tokens` is slow because it requires a linear search through the array. A `set()` is more appropriate here.

Comment: @FrancisAvila - Thank you for your comments.  I didn't take the first line as the header, but rather a file designator.  Have changed the list to a set; appreciate you mentioning this.

Comment: Actually, you changed the list to a generator. This code will now not work at all since the generator can't be rewound.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a dictionary for this:

```
filenames = ['file1', 'file2']

mapping = {}

for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as handle:
        for line in handle:
            key, _, value = line.partition('=')
            mapping[key] = value
```

You can then sort `mapping` by the key name and then write the result to your output file.

Comment: I guess I suck at dictionaries. I tried sorting mapping by convertnig them to a list- sorted_list = [x for x in mapping.iteritems()]
 
sorted_list.sort(key=lambda x: x[0]) # sort by key . What do I do now? Should I be removing duplicate keys and write it to a file?

Comment: @Illusionist: You can't have duplicate keys. Just write the list to a file.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting your expected output is because your tokens `IA_ITD_Worst_V` and `IA_ITD_WORST_V` are not the same--they have different cases.

If you want tokens to match *case insensitively*, lowercase them before comparing them. E.g. `'IA_ITD_Worst_V'.lower() == 'IA_ITD_WORST_V'.lower()`.

Your code is very inefficient, however. A much better way would be to keep the allowed tokens in a set, although it forces you to keep them in memory. If the list of tokens is too big to keep in memory, use a database.

Alternate implementation:

```
def tokenize(line):
    return line.split('=', 1)[0].strip().lower()

with open('file1', 'r') as f1:
    f1.readline()
    f1tokens = frozenset(tokenize(line) for line in f1)

with open('file2', 'r') as f2, open('commonfile.txt', 'w') as out:
    f2.readline()
    out.writelines(line for line in f2 if tokenize(line) in f1tokens)
```

Comment: Thanks, the files are like 10k lines each, is that too big?

Comment: That's tens of megabytes, so probably not.

Answer (score 1):

As you said there are more efficient/cleaner ways of doing this, but to answer your specific question: start by removing this lines:

```
line1=f1.readline()
line2=f2.readline()
```

You are skipping lines there.

EDIT: Added the following after you added that data example.

It seems you want a case insensitive condition, this should fix that:

```
if tokenname.lower() == line1.split('=')[0].strip().lower():
```